# Can't use Path(file) without throwing an exception

Tags: python

```
    try:
        print(filePath)
        my_file = Path(filePath)
    except ValueError:
        print ValueError
```

Trying to run this code keeps throwing an error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)`

The value blowing it up is:
`Kellyanne Conway: Giuliani’s Withdrawal From Consideration A ‘Mutual Decision’ | MTP Daily | MSNBC.opus`

I've tried encoding this string in ascii and unicode and it hasn't worked. How can I check if the file exists properly, thanks.

Comment: And what is `Path`?

Comment: `from pathlib import Path`

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  It matters.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938079/why-python2-and-python3-treat-same-windows-directory-differently and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/ (search for "ASCII")

Comment: This binary is 2.7.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use os.path instead of pathlib.

```
import os

print os.path.exists(filePath)
print os.path.isfile(filePath)
```

pathlib prior to Python 3 doesn't handle non-ASCII character well.  See:

[Why Python2 and Python3 treat same windows directory differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938079/why-python2-and-python3-treat-same-windows-directory-differently)

and

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/ (search for "ASCII")

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I'm out of upvotes but will vote this when I get some again, thx

Comment: I tried to use Python 3 but ran into some SSL error